# Is it good to combine weights, punchbag, and cardio in same workout?

Tags: workout-routines

I'm thinking of doing a 5 day split day 1 chest day 2 back day 3 legs day 4 shoulders day 5 arms,each day consisting of 30 minutes weights 10 minutes of bag work, and 20 minutes of cardio. Is that a good idea, or would I be be overtraining?

Comment: This is not a very specific question. There's just not enough detail for this to stand on its own. Nor does it appear well-researched.

Comment: It would be nice for someone to find or write a definitive answer on "is (this proposed workout) overtraining?" for all possible workouts.

Comment: What's your goal?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen professional Muay Thai fighters complete 2hour+ morning sessions that included running, sparring/bag work and strength training - so yes, it's quite possible to do what you described - or even endure much longer training sessions on a daily basis...but like other people mentioned, your level of fitness will decide whether you're over-training or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, but it depends what your goals are. However IMO you may not want to do that everyday as that could be a cause for over training if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's only an hour's worth of work, and it covers a wide variety of parts of the body and types of exercise, so you should be fine. Just listen to your body and take breaks where you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Overall its an good option you are targeting every parts of you body, but be sure you do not overdo it. You exercise routine totally depends upon your endurance level. Try consulting your doctor if you have any prolong illness. Just remember don't over do it, `progress gradually`. Take a rest keep your heart beat bellow 100 and hit again.